# Calculate all the possible tuples and its count by matching the value of another column in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, tuples

```
I have a data frame of 12 customers and four products that they purchased as given below.


cust_id         product
1               tv
1               phone
2               bat
2               ball
3               bat
4               ball
4               bat
4               tv
4               phone
5               tv
6               bat
7               bat
7               ball
7               tv
8               phone
8               tv
8               bat
9               bat
9               ball
10              phone
10              bat
11              phone
12              tv
```

From the above I would like to prepare below data frame.

From the above data frame I would like to prepare below data frame using pandas.

```
product_combination             number_of_customers
(bat, ball, phone, tv)          1 
(bat, ball, phone)              0 
(bat, ball, tv)                 1
```

---------- dataframe ----------

```
customers = {
    "cust_id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12],
    "product": ["tv", "phone", "bat", "ball", "bat", "ball", "bat", "tv", "phone", "tv", "bat", "bat", "ball", "tv", "phone", "tv", "bat", "bat", "ball", "phone", "bat", "phone", "tv"],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel there should be a faster way to achieve this, but the following should work.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import combinations

customers = {
    "cust_id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
                7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12],
    "product": ["tv", "phone", "bat", "ball", "bat", 
                "ball", "bat", "tv", "phone", "tv", 
                "bat", "bat", "ball", "tv", "phone", 
                "tv", "bat", "bat", "ball", "phone", 
                "bat", "phone", "tv"],
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(customers)

# create list with tuples combinations 1 <= n <= len(unique_products)
products = sorted(df['product'].unique())
n = len(products)
combs = [comb for i in range(n) for comb in combinations(products, i + 1)]
combs.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

# groupby product per customer, turn into list, next turn into sorted tuple
temp = df.groupby('cust_id', as_index=False)['product'].agg(list)
temp['product'] = temp['product'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))

# perform groupby count
s = temp.groupby('product')['cust_id'].count()

# create result df and map groupby count
result = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(combs), columns=['product_combination'])
result['number_of_customers'] = result['product_combination'].map(s)

# fillna with zeros
result = result.fillna(0)
```

```
print(result)

       product_combination  number_of_customers
0   (ball, bat, phone, tv)                  1.0
1       (ball, bat, phone)                  0.0
2          (ball, bat, tv)                  1.0
3        (ball, phone, tv)                  0.0
4         (bat, phone, tv)                  1.0
5              (ball, bat)                  2.0
6            (ball, phone)                  0.0
7               (ball, tv)                  0.0
8             (bat, phone)                  1.0
9                (bat, tv)                  0.0
10             (phone, tv)                  1.0
11                 (ball,)                  0.0
12                  (bat,)                  2.0
13                (phone,)                  1.0
14                   (tv,)                  2.0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I am getting following error - ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 12), indices imply (1, 12) - while generating "temp" data frame.

Comment: Odd.. So, the problem is on this line: `temp = df.groupby('cust_id', as_index=False)['product'].agg(list)`, right? Could you check `print(type(list))`, does it print: `<class 'type'>`? If not, you will have overwritten the built-in Python function. Reset your kernel in that case. Or does the error on a different line?

Comment: yes the error is with the same line. `print(type(list)) ` it prints `<class 'type'>`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error, I'm afraid. Is your df *exactly* as above (i.e. `df = pd.DataFrame(customers)`), or do you have other columns / rows as well? Also, maybe you can check your version of pandas: `print(pd.__version__)`. What does it say? If you open a new kernel and simply copy/paste my exact code, and run it, does the error persist?

Comment: my pandas version is `1.2.4`. The error persists. Anyway thank you so much for your great answer

Comment: Not sure, but then it might well be a version problem. The current version of pandas is already 1.4.3 (and the one I'm on). Are you in the position to upgrade? `pip install pandas==1.4.3` should probably work.